# unable to get rid of space between header

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This seems to be a css problem. I have tried setting the `margin`, `line-height`, etc. But I can't close the gap between the header and the angular view - which is in body directly. Please refer plunk share here.

[image]
Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/f6ILSWZzzufR4q3qrTW0?p=preview

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s258/sh/ac1c45ac-4a4e-40a0-a26c-33d4d4f4c41c/56e4301f4c937e9d2ed7ee737dda24f9

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5MsJSFqhEhBEeHfPzUAb?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

The navbar class has a margin-bottom of 20px

Comment: @deostroll, I checked the HTML elements with the Google dev toolbar. Found the margin. You can either adjust your bootstrap css or remove the margin-bottom from that specific element with margin-bottom: 0 !important

Comment: You don't want to be using !important in your CSS.

Comment: @codeepic true but you want to override the bootstrap styles (to be able to use from CDN), other option is to use your own bootstrap version and adjust the navbar css

Comment: The other option is to use the same css selector used in bootstrap styles and reuse it with `margin-bottom: 0;` in your styles. I've been doing it for all sorts of predefined css styles (jquery plugins, css frameworks).

Comment: @codeepic you can select it with ID's to get an higher weight as an alternative to !important, i would not simply add the same class to your css  but i would select it on ID to get the heighest weight

Comment: @matthijsb - it has essentially the same effect. If your styles have the same specificity but are loaded after default bootstrap styles, they overwrite the bootstrap styles. On the other hand, if you have multiple DOM elements which you want to target, you don't want to be using same id for all of them - that's where you use classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71282/discussion-between-codeepic-and-matthijsb).

Answer (score 2):

in your navbar remove the margin-bottom from css where you define like this

```
.navbar
{
position: relative;
min-height: 50px;
/* margin-bottom: 20px;  Remove this from css*/
border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

i hope it may help you thanks

Comment: so you can set margin 0 in the tag as style attribute it cannot effect to your other components having class navbar

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [working solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/vbqGt4m5PwC03EMXiEHI?p=preview)

Basically, you need to add `margin-bottom: 0;` to `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin:0">
```

does it